# Firebase FCM IOS don´t send Apple apns payload

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging

I have 3 apps, 2 are working well and are receiving pushs from FCM, but one of them does not receive pushs.

I don´t know why, but my other apps receive a Push Notification like this:

```
{
aps =     {
    alert =         {
        body = "body here";
        title = "title here;
    };
    badge = 3;
    "content-available" = 1;
};
"gcm.message_id" = "0:1468862214187339%9c127a139c127a13";
```

}

But in my other app, I receive messages like this (without aps body):

```
{
"collapse_key" = "...";
from = 1003897668292;
notification =     {
    body = "body here";
    e = 1;
    title = "title here";
};
```

}

Well, so I have some questions?

I did the same process in both applications.

- I use the default swizzling
- I created the p12 certificate to send Push Messages and I did upload it to the Firebase Console.

Does anyone know any reason for Firebase send messages with a different format? On the server I'm sending messages in the same way.

I would like to receive messages with the "aps/alert/body" format.

kind regards

Comment: Could you add your request you are using to send to the question? I'm seeing in one case you have a badge and in another there is no badge, so adding the request may clear up that confusion.

Comment: This is my json, but I´m still sending to old GCM endpoint:  {"notification":{"title":"b title here1","body":"subtitle here"},"content_available":true,"data":{"post_id":"1","push_id":"1","msg":"b message here"},"registration_ids":["fnHx6gUzTHY:APA91bE_NZkk3z6p_H42s7c2ma9qGCpJPxAsaHjhKEyAdHaSKOEzPe8eMpLLWbSAAmUgQuEYjUgsa5_NGsi4yn3u1HbmqfYEL64WFDr-SB3ocfCrG1qJC_5NG_NqibcOFV_Fk58AhUOC"],"priority":"high"}

Comment: But my question is: Why sometimes Firebase sends notification with the "aps" format, and why "sometimes" it sends with the "notification" format ? I have two apps that receives notification with the "aps" format. And one of them receives the data with the "notification" format. This happens even if I send the push notification using the Firebase Console and with "high" priority.  Also, if I write my code using the native Apple APNS I receive pushs with the correct aps format, but I´m trying to migrate to Firebase.

Comment: Could you try it again, I'm not able to reproduce this and there were some APNs sandbox issues a few days ago that have been resolved. Notifications messages like what you are sending are sent through APNs and thus should always be wrapped in the aps object.

Comment: Arthur, thanks. Its working now. But I didnt change nothing in the code... I just did a "pod update".

Comment: @rlecheta I am facing the same problem with my iOS application. I am getting the second body you mentioned when I send from server, while sending from console, I get the first body. Could you please help.

Comment: In my case, it was my mistake. If you have any problem with your push certificate, Firebase you not send the Push message throught Apple APNS. But I don't remember what I did, because it was a long time ago, sorry.